# What's this footwork technique called?

Tags: karate, footwork

In movie "**Never Back Down: No Surrender (2016)**", Michael Jai White is seen practising a footwork technique shown below.

[image: Footwork]

Is there any such technique in Karate? If so, what is it?

Comment: Incidentally, I found a promotional video where it demonstrates this, albeit only for a moment:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1YmTkpUw1sk
Warning, NSFW. Language.

Comment: @SteveWeigand: Ah yes, about 43 seconds in. Good catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say without better context, but that looks like a standard Side Step drill, as seen [here](https://youtu.be/fszMnO84iJ0?t=10s). Diagonal step in, kick. Repeat on the other side. The duct tape provides a tactile and visual guide for the steps. The image on the wall provides a target.

You can see similar duct-tape diagrams in [this boxing footwork tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLmX-umfd_0) and I know that my SCA light fencing class similarly used them to teach the technique of a diagonal step and counter-attack.

As Steve Weigand noted in the comments, it is commonly covered in karate. I personally experienced one-step drills in Tang Soo Do (later changed to Chun Kuk Do) and Tae Kwan Do.

Comment: I agree. It looks like a side-step drill like the one you linked to. It should be covered in karate, yes. It may not be in any specific kata, but it should either be taught or learned on ones own for sparring.